# htaccess redirect not working with URLs with parameters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect index.php?action=this&id=1 to index.php?action=this&id=2

I tried the code below in my .htaccess but it didn't help

```
redirect 301 index.php?action=this&id=1 http://mysite.com/index.php?action=this&id=2
```

What am i doing wrong here? what could be a workaround?

Comment: As per documentation URL should start with leading slash (as already mentioned by Shaikh). Unfortunately `Redirect` directive does not work with query string parameters -- only with path part (in your case it will be `index.php`). Your only hope -- is to use **mod_rewrite**. Please check if it is present/enabled on your server - if yes, then I may help you here.

Comment: See my answer -- sorry for a delay -- did when I had a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to match specific query string you **have** to use **mod_rewrite**. Please check if it is installed/allowed on your host. The rule in this case will be something like this:

```
# most likely be required for rewrite rules to function properly
Options +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

# Activate Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# actual rule
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action=this&id=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /index.php?action=this&id=2 [R=301,L]
```

This needs to be placed in .htaccess in website root folder. If placed anywhere else some small changes may be required.

This rule will only redirect `/index.php?action=this&id=1` to `/index.php?action=this&id=2` and no other URLs (just as you asked in your question).

Answer (score 2):

You could try just adding this on the page that you want redirected

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=index?action=this&id=2">
```

Comment: no i don't want meta refresh. it's kinda not possible here in my situation.

Answer (score 1):

just add the forward slash before the first url like

```
Redirect 301 /index.php?action=this&id=1 http://mysite.com/index.php?action=this&id=2
```