# redirect .aspx with query string to html page using htaccess

Tags: asp.net, .htaccess, redirect

We have migrated from a windows server to linux server. I trying to redirect all the .aspx urls to html urls.

The static pages works fine so say if I used

```
Redirect 301 /contact.aspx http://mysite.com/contact.html
```

but when I try to add a redirect like

```
Redirect 301 /products.aspx?cid=30&bid=5 http://mysite.com/category/books.html
```

the redirect is not working.

Any advice is highly appreciated

Comment: Check this answer out [htaccess redirect not working with URLs with parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10273246/752527)

Comment: are you using IIS to perform the redirect?